# VK Auth - ошибка аутентификации при передаче дополнительного параметра state

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

При попытке аутентификации с передачей дополнительного параметра state выдает следующую ошибку:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Security Error"}
```

Код для аутентификации:

```
var authURI = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=123456789&display=page&redirect_uri=http://test1.ru&response_type=token&v=5.57&state=' + searchQuery;
window.location.replace(encodeURI(authURI));
```

При этом ошибка возникает только в том случае, если `searchQuery` является строкой, состоящей из нескольких слов (т.е. с пробелами). Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А если пробел заменить на `%20`?

Comment: @post_zeew я думал encodeURI тоже самое делает, сейчас попробую.

Comment: И еще, попробуйте перелогиниться под этим аккаунтом в браузере.

Comment: @post_zeew %20 сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: Строку нельзя отправлять в таком виде. Помню, делал мессенджер и все работало, кроме некоторых аппаратов с Android 4.2.2. Делайте сразу для всех версий и не стоит заканчивать тестирование если заработало на Lollipop. Обделайте **все** параметры `URLEncoder`-ом, мой вам совет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменной `authURI` замените пробелы на `%20`.